# google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError: mapping values are not allowed here

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app.yaml

When trying to start amy gae application i recieve this weird error that does not really give a information about what is wrong.

```
raise yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError(e)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventListenerYAMLError: mapping values are not allowed here
  in "C:\Program Files\Google\Cloud SDK\helloworld\app.yaml", line 8, column 11
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?

My app.yaml looks as follows:

```
application: pivotal-stacker-729
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /data/.*
    script: data.py

- url: /.*
    script: asklogin.py
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have too many spaces. Python is very picky about spacing. You]ll also need the threadsafe directive and to update to python27. Bellow should work:

```
application: pivotal-stacker-729
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: false

handlers:
- url: /data/.*
  script: data.py

- url: /.*
  script: asklogin.py
```

[This is a good tool to play with when having yaml issues](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/)

Comment: app.yaml is, well, YAML, not Python, so Python's pickiness about spacing is irrelevant.

Comment: True, maybe it was tabs then that was causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

For people unfamiliar with YAML, the invalid syntax might be above the line referenced by the error. In my case I was missing a colon one line above.